# Retrieve the lunar phases to diary.org as a record

Tags: org-babel

I tried to record  the sunrise and sunset info to the diary

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :tangle yes
(sunrise-sunset)
;;(lunar-phases)
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: Sunrise 6:57am (CST), sunset 5:00pm (CST) at 40.0N, 116.3E (10:03 hrs daylight)
```

`sunrise-sunset` worked as expected,

But to lunar-phases

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :tangle yes
;;(sunrise-sunset)
(lunar-phases)
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: Computing phases of the moon...done
```

How could get the lunar phases as it print to the echo area?

Answer (score 1):

In the following example, the month has been hard-coded to be the 11th month of the year (i.e., November), and the year has been hard-coded to be the year 2019.

[How did I come up with this example?  I typed `M-x find-function RET lunar-phases RET`; and, then I placed my cursor on `calendar-lunar-phases` and repeated the `find-function`; and, then I extracted the guts of that latter function and came up with the examples below based upon the extracted code.]

```lisp
(let ((month 11)
      (year 2019))
  (require 'lunar)
  (mapcar
    (lambda (x)
      (format "%s: %s %s" (calendar-date-string (car x))
                          (lunar-phase-name (nth 2 x))
                          (cadr x)))
    (lunar-phase-list month year)))
```

For a pretty formatted *return value*, use ....

```lisp
(let ((month 11)
      (year 2019))
  (require 'lunar)
  (mapconcat
     (lambda (x)
       (format "%s: %s %s" (calendar-date-string (car x))
                           (lunar-phase-name (nth 2 x))
                           (cadr x)))
     (lunar-phase-list month year)
     "\n"))
```

Which gives us a *return value* as follows:

```
Monday, November 4, 2019: First Quarter Moon 2:24am (PST)
Tuesday, November 12, 2019: Full Moon 5:34am (PST)
Tuesday, November 19, 2019: Last Quarter Moon 1:17pm (PST)
Tuesday, November 26, 2019: New Moon 7:08am (PST)
Tuesday, December 3, 2019: First Quarter Moon 10:59pm (PST)
Wednesday, December 11, 2019: Full Moon 9:11pm (PST)
Wednesday, December 18, 2019: Last Quarter Moon 9:03pm (PST)
Wednesday, December 25, 2019: New Moon 9:16pm (PST)
Thursday, January 2, 2020: First Quarter Moon 8:47pm (PST)
Friday, January 10, 2020: Full Moon 11:20am (PST)
Friday, January 17, 2020: Last Quarter Moon 5:04am (PST)
Friday, January 24, 2020: New Moon 1:44pm (PST)
```